# Spynner install issues

Tags: python, spynner

Running Mac OS Lion

I was trying to do some scraping with `Mechanize` but I was having massive issues with javascript. So, after some browsing I decided to try out `Spynner`. I've tried to download it with both pip and easy_install but I get the same error each time:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-root/autopy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-53vGzx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-root/autopy
```

Looking for some help (or maybe another suggestion rather than Spynner).

I have XCode installed and updated (along with command line tools).

I've made the links between gcc and gcc-4.2 (`ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.21`)

I have virtualenv installed. I only mention that because I've noticed that a lot of the same problems occur with its installation as well.